# Visual Flow Lookup from Lookup

Tags: visual-flows, fast-lookup

Can I not have a fast/record lookup that returns a collection of IDs and then do a second fast/record lookup using that collection of IDs in the filter criteria?

I think the answer to this is that flows don't allow it, but I want to confirm.

Comment: do you want to achieve this in same screen or different screen?

Comment: @SantanuBoral This is actually an autolaunched flow. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: Not sure if this can be done, but it would be use the first fast lookup to populate an sObject Collection variable, then loop through that one by one to lookup the other records into an sObject variable and add those to a different sObject Collection. Going to see if I can do this in a dev org.

Comment: Thanks @DaveHumm, but I would like to stay away from queries within the loop so that I don't hit limits and generally slow performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward and short answer is, currently what you're trying to achieve is not possible in Flow.

Possible solution: - There is a plugin created by a community member (I think I heard about it on success community workflow group) to overcome it.

Comment: Yes, hitting the flow limitations. The only other workround I could see would be having an invocable apex class called by the flow which does get round some of the limits and perfomrance issues with bulk work using flow.